# POST requests from jQuery to PHP stuck if POST data exceeds several hundred characters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, post

I have a plain ajax request being initiated by jQuery to a PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"script.php",
  data: data,
  type: "POST"
  // error & success handlers here
});
```

If the data (could be JSON, could be a binary file), exceed a few hundred characters in length, the POST request never completes, it just hangs there. No errors in apache log or JS console, no other indication as to what might be going on.

Fiddling with php.ini post_max_data and other settings did not yield any results and all settings I could think of are set to very permissive values.

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 server with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5.9.

What am I missing?

Comment: jQuery `$.ajax` have multiple callbacks, which can be used for debugging.. like `statusCode`, `error` etc.. try them and then see the response .. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The `post_max_data` config parameter is probably the issue.

Add (or replace) the following in `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
```

Also try this in your `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
```

Note that some server hosts might not allow to add these to `.htaccess`, but it looks like that might not be an issue for you.

Comment: `data (could be JSON, could be a binary file), exceed a few hundred characters in length`, it can't be in MB's, few hundred can get covered in KB's

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, these parameters are set quite high and should definitely cover a kilobyte of data.